# add remove class jquery not working

Tags: jquery, html

i am using the simple jquery addClass and removeClass function to toggle the class of the div on click but its not working. its working first time but second time its not working.

here is the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/chirag007/3xees0j8/

here is the jquery code.

```
$(".open-menu").click(function (e) { 
    $(".open-menu").addClass("close-menu1");
    $(".open-menu").removeClass("open-menu");
});

  $(".close-menu1").click(function (e1) {
      $(".close-menu1").addClass("open-menu");
      $(".close-menu").removeClass("close-menu1");
});
```

thanks for your help..

Comment: Just so you know, you could use `toggleClass("open-menu close-menu1");` instead. http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/3xees0j8/5/

Comment: Since you are expecting the event handlers to change based on the changed classes you need to use event delegation

Comment: In last line $(".close-menu") your class is close-menu1 not close-menu. And also need to use delegate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not working because you aren't using [delegation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

The jquery is attached to the elemnts which have the class (`open-menu`) on DOM ready (that's why the first click **is** working), but when the class (`close-menu`) is attached later dynamically it doesn't have the function attached to the event [like here](http://jsfiddle.net/3xees0j8/3/).

try

```
$(document).on("click", "<selector>", function(){
....
});
```

[see updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xees0j8/6/)

Answer (score 1):

`close-menu1` doesn't exist at the time you are creating the click event handlers.

You *can* change this to being a delegate to fix the solution, however a cleaner solution would be to have a class on the element which is never removed, and then detect which other classes are applied within the single event handler.

```
<div class="toggle-menu open-menu">menu</div>

$(".toggle-menu").click(function (e) {

    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.hasClass("open-menu")){

        $this.addClass("close-menu1")
             .removeClass("open-menu");        
    }
    else
    {
         $this.addClass("open-menu")
              .removeClass("close-menu1");
    }    

    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `event delegation` and `toggleClass` in jquery

```
$(document).on("click", ".toggle-menu" ,function (e) { 

    $(this).toggleClass("open-menu close-menu1");

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3xees0j8/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this
http://jsfiddle.net/s7hmv6kq/

```
$("body").on('click','.open-menu',function (e) { alert('b');
    $(".open-menu").addClass("close-menu1");
    $(".open-menu").removeClass("open-menu");
});

 $("body").on('click','.close-menu1',function (e1) {alert('a');
    $(".close-menu1").addClass("open-menu");
    $(".close-menu1").removeClass("close-menu1");
});
```